# Pass datagridview to event - Combine Events

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two datagridviews in a form.  I have multiple events that do the same thing for each DGV.  Is it possible to pass the DGV to the event so I can remove one of them?

```
private void mainLogDGV_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == mainLogDGV.Columns["Comment"].Index)
    {
        mainLogDGV.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}

private void filteredLogDGV_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == filteredLogDGV.Columns["Comment"].Index)
    {
        filteredLogDGV.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Look at the sender parameter. Cast it to DataGridView and you're on your way..

Comment: Two gridview have same columns or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

```
private void mainLogDGV_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (((DataGridView)sender).Name == dataGridView1.Name) 
   { '//Grid one Process }
   else if (((DataGridView)sender).Name == dataGridView2.Name) 
   { '//Grid TweProcess  }

}

private void filteredLogDGV_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
      if (((DataGridView)sender).Name == dataGridView1.Name) 
      { '//Grid one Process }
      else if (((DataGridView)sender).Name == dataGridView2.Name) 
      { '//Grid TweProcess  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the calling DGV using the following;

```
DataGridView SendingDGV = ((DataGridViewCell)sender).DataGridView
```

then use SendingDGV as the reference to make your changes.